# map the term set to site column of SharePoint Online OR Office 365 with powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I have to create **site column** with metadata type and have to assigne it with the TermSet with powershell or CSOM with SharePoint Online OR Office 365.
Is it feasible and how?

Thanks,
Ram.